# GraphQL/Apollo-Server-Express Error: Cannot return null for non-nullable field Mutation Data: null

Tags: graphql, apollo-server

So far all tested queries and mutations are working other than this one.

I'm receiving this error on the Apollo playground.

**"message":**

```
Cannot return null for non-nullable field Mutation.createComment
...
```

**"extrensions":**

```
...
Data: null
```

I've tried most if not all the google and stackoverflow resolutions I can find and now I'm reaching out for help. Any help that I can get resolving this issue will be immensely appreciated.

**Post Model:**

```
const postSchema = new Schema({
  body: String,
  username: String,
  createdAt: String,
  comments: [
    {
      body: String,
      username: String,
      createdAt: String,
    },
  ],
  likes: [
    {
      username: String,
      createdAt: String,
    },
  ],
  // Linking the user model
  user: {
    type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: "users",
  },
});
```

**Comments Resolver:**

```
Mutation: {
    createComment: async (_, { postId, body, username }, context) => {
      const { username } = checkAuth(context);
      if (body.trim === "") {
        throw new UserInputError("Empty comment", {
          errors: {
            body: "Comment body can not be empty",
          },
        });
      }

      const post = await Post.findById(postId);

      if (post) {
        post.comments.unshift({
          body,
          username,
          createdAt: new Date().toISOString(),
        });
        await post.save();
        return post;
      } else throw new UserInputError("Post not found");
},
```

**Type Defs:**

```
  type Post {
    id: ID!
    body: String!
    createdAt: String!
    username: String!
    comments: [Comment]!
    likes: [Like]!
    likeCount: Int!
    commentCount: Int!
  }
  type Comment {
    id: ID!
    createdAt: String!
    username: String!
    body: String!
  }
  type Like {
    id: ID!
    createdAt: String!
    username: String!
  }
  type User {
    id: ID!
    email: String!
    token: String!
    username: String!
    createdAt: String!
    confirmed: Boolean!
  }
  input RegisterInput {
    username: String!
    password: String!
    confirmPassword: String!
    email: String!
  }
  type Query {
    getUsers: [User]
    getPosts: [Post]
    getPost(postId: ID!): Post
  }
  type Mutation {
    register(registerInput: RegisterInput): User!
    login(email: String!, password: String!): User!
    createPost(body: String!): Post!
    deletePost(postId: ID!): String!
    createComment(postId: ID!, body: String!, username: String!): Post!
    deleteComment(postId: ID!, commentId: ID!): Post!
    likePost(postId: ID!): Post!
  }
  type Subscription {
    newPost: Post!
  }
```

**Mutation im using in the Apollo Playground:**

```
mutation createComment{
  createComment(
    postId: "6106db3a0e9e783e98b996a4", 
    body: "This is a new comment", 
    username: "Random user"
) {
  id
  comments {
    id
    body
    createdAt
    username
  }
  commentCount
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

After endlessly trying all the solutions available on the net it actually turned out to be an import error in my index.js file for my graphql resolvers.

I had **const commentsResolvers = require("./users");**

When it should have been **const commentsResolvers = require("./comments");**